# Install other modules from hook_install

Tags: updating, installation

Is it possible to run command of the same functionality as drush pm-download from hook_install or hook_update_n? If not, what other alternative solutions do I have to automatically download and install modules and dependencies from a custom site deployer module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to run command of the same functionality as drush pm-download from hook_install or hook_update_n?

If the web server user has permissions to write to the modules folder (which is in itself a security risk), then yes, you can do that. Writing it wouldn't be trivial, of course, but you can get a lot of the necessary code from Drush.

If the web server user doesn't have permissions to write to the modules folder, then no, it's not possible.

> If not, what other alternative solutions do I have to automatically download and install modules and dependencies from a custom site deployer module?

If your web-server is properly secured, then your only option is to invoke the script (whatever form that may take) as a user with sufficient privileges.